# Integration by parts involving weights and div operator on the half space

Tags: real-analysis, integration, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^n_+$ and let $f,g\in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^n).$ Thus the functions $f$ and $g$ do not necessarily vanish at the boundary of $\Omega.$ I am considering an integral of the form,
$$\int_\Omega (\nabla f \cdot \nabla g) x_n^{\alpha}dx$$
which I think should be equal to,
$$\int_\Omega (\nabla f \cdot \nabla g) x_n^{\alpha}dx = -\int_\Omega \operatorname{div}(x_n^{\alpha}\nabla f) g dx + \text{boundary term}$$
but I am not sure what the boundary term is. In Evans book, the integration by parts formula suggests that
$$\text{boundary term} = \int_{\partial \Omega}g x_n^{\alpha} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}dS$$
but I am not sure if this is the correct expression. Any remarks as to wether the above computation is correct or not will be much appreciated.

Edit: I am guessing that the boundary term is equal to zero since on the boundary $x_n=0.$

Comment: Why don't you write out the integrand explicitly i.e $\nabla f \cdot \nabla g = f_{x_{1}} g_{x_{1}} + f_{x_{2}} + g_{x_{2}} + \dots$, multiply it by the multiindex $x^{\alpha}_{n}$ and integrate term by term?